# Delete part of index name in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, key

in PHP, is it possible to cut the |xyz part away from the key names?
The array looks like this:

```
    array(30) {
  ["1970-01-01|802"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "176"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(10) "1970-01-01"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Vorschau"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(16) "vorschau-v15-176"
  }
  ["1970-01-01|842"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "176"
    ["datum"]=>
    string(10) "1970-01-01"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) "Vorschau"
    ["alias"]=>
    string(16) "vorschau-v15-176"
  } ...
```

Thank you for your help,

toni

Comment: You just have to rewrite your array. This will result in collisions though since before the `|xyz` the values are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you might use this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach( $oldArray as $key => $value ) {

   $newArray[ substr( $key, 0, 10 ) ] = $value;

}
```

Or modify the array in-place:

```
foreach( $someArray as $key => $value ) {

   unset( $someArray[ $key ] );
   $someArray[ substr( $key, 0, 10 ) ] = $value;

}
```

**Both solutions will loose value**

Since the keys in your source array are

```
   1970-01-01|802
   1970-01-01|842
```

the output array will loose some array values: Both keys get mapped to a single destination key:

```
   1970-01-01
```

**Keeping all values**

If you **don't want to loose values**, try this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach( $someArray as $key => $value ) {

   $newKey = substr( $key, 0, 10 );
   if ( ! isset( $newArray[ $newKey ] )) {
      $newArray[ $newKey ] = array();
   }
   $newArray[ $newKey ][] = $value;

}
```

Result array structure of this solution:

```
array( 
  '1970-01-01' => 
    array(
       0 => ...,
       1 => ...
    ),
  '1970-01-02' => 
    array(
       0 => ...,
       1 => ...,
       2 => ...
    ),
  ...
);
```

Comment: Based on his example though that will yield a single array element. With the key of `1970-01-01`

Comment: @Orangepill Sure. But it conforms to the specification: Drop the |xyz part of all keys. In case *t Brook*'s specification is incomplete, so is the output ;-)

Comment: mhhh exactly thats what happening I´m loosing  one key. Not good. Have to think about this again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of.. just create a new array with the trimmed key, then set the old aray equal to the new one.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($arrayList as $key => $data) {

    $keyParts = explode("|", $key);
    $newArray[$keyParts[0]] = $data;

}

$arrayList = $newArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible but in this case you would end up with 2 of the same array keys.

```
["1970-01-01"] and ["1970-01-01"]
```

The xyz behind it is required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `preg_replace`:

```
$keys = preg_replace('/(.+)\|\d+/', '$1', array_keys($arr));
$arr = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```